# no meu código sempre está dando o seguinte erro 'name (nome) is not defined'

Tags: python, python-3.x, recuperação-de-erros

print('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')
print('Seja bem vindo(a) a tela de registros dos koalas!')
print('se registre agora, é simples, rapido e fácil!')
print('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')
YoN = input('você deseja se registrar agora? [Sim ou Não]: ')

if YoN == Sim or YoN == sim:

```
print('muito bem, vamos começar o seu registro!')

print('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')
Rlogin = input('digite o nome que será usado no seu login: ')
Rsenha = input('digite a senha que será usada no seu login: ')
print('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')

print('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')
print('seu nome de login é: {}'.format(Rlogin))
print('sua senha será: {}'.format(Rsenha))
print('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')
YoN2 = input('Você confirma? [Sim ou Não]: ')

while YoN2 == nao or YoN2 == não:

    print('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')
    Rlogin = input('digite o nome que será usado no seu login: ')
    Rsenha = input('digite a senha que será usada no seu login: ')
    print('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')


    YoN2 = input('Você confirma? [Sim ou Não]: ')
else:

    if YoN2 == sim:

        print('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')
        print('Muito Bem, Você está oficialmente registrado!')
        print('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')
        print('SEJA BEM VINDO!')
        print('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')

    else:

        if YoN == Não or YoN == nao:

            print('Ok, até a proxima!')
```

os erros que sempre dão são os seguintes:
(Unresolved reference 'Sim')
(Unresolved reference 'sim')
(Unresolved reference 'não')
(Unresolved reference 'nao')

Comment: sim, nao e os demais deveriam ser strings

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fala amigo, tudo certo?

Só transformar o Sim e Não em String, utilizando aspas.

Também para melhorar o código, deixe-os sem o sensitive-case, transformando a variável para maiúsculo ou tudo minúsculo